# Access to a object of class in Matlab

Tags: matlab

while I run a sample code that it tried access to object on class
it shows me this error
 "??? Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods."
how can I access a object on a class in Matlab.
 thanks.

Comment: ok, can you show your code? It's hard to recognize error without any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Matlab's Object Oriented approach to access its object properties and values. MATLAB's OOP is not the same, but similar to existing High-Level languages such as C++ an Java. Without looking at your code, I can only supply the following example (can be found in various other places on the web):

```
classdef SomeClassData

properties
   Data;
end

methods
% Constructor
  function obj=SomeClassData(dataValues)
     obj.Data=dataValues;
  end

  function View(obj)
     display(obj.Data)
  end

  function x = getData()
     x = obj.Data;
end

end
```

You should check out MATHWORKS website for further details on how to utilise their OOP structure for your own needs. My understanding is that all the primitive MATLAB types should have their `getData()` method enabled for user's to see inside the objects. I used OOP to design some custom MATLAB libraries back in 2009, so remember these from those time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple example, you have a class circle with the property diameter. To access the diameter of  a circle a, you have to use the object:

```
a=Circle(3)
a.diameter
```

What you did instead was something like `Circle.diameter`

To fix this, either make it a static property, or access it via a class instance.